# Dynamic import base on props name in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Dynamic import base on props name in react

```
import { a, b, c } from 'some-package/theme' // should not import everything here

const MyComp = ({ theme, ...other }) => { 

  console.log(theme) //can be a, b, c, d, e etc
  return(<MyCompInner />) 
}

export default MyComp
```

How can I do dynamic import from 'some-package/theme' ? the prop of theme can be a, b, c and more. Theme props is the option, but I have to import the value from 'some-package/theme' before I supply it to `<MyCompInner />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `require()` for this. Unlike `import` which has to be at the top, you can use `require()` anywhere in your code.

```
const MyComp = ({ theme, ...other }) => { 

  const t = require('some-package/theme/' + theme);
  return(<MyCompInner theme={t} />) 
}

export default MyComp
```

Comment: can't do import here? why `require` would work? Is that a apart of jsx?

Comment: @Melissa92, not entirely sure, but probably some kind of restriction in the bundling process.

Comment: yeah thanks so much for this!! Although enyzme test won't let that to work.